# How to wait for ManualResetEvent.WaitOne() to be reached before moving on?

Tags: c#, multithreading, manualresetevent

I'm trying to use ManualResetEvent to make a semaphore-like situation and I have placed `WaitOne`, `Set` and `Reset` in their right places. The `WaitOne` instruction is called in a listener thread and is places right after a tcp reading:

```
var networkStream = _clientSocket.GetStream();
networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, Convert.ToInt32(_clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize));
_mainthreadControl.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite);
```

And `Set` and `Reset` instructions are called in another thread, so the socket won't get competed over:

```
try
{
    //some code
    _mainthreadControl.Reset();
    //some code that uses the same socket as above
    _mainthreadControl.Set();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //ignored
}
```

But I need the code to stop when it reaches `Reset`, and only continue after the `WaitOne` is reached (and executed), so the code below `Reset` only runs after the competing thread is waiting.

I don't know if I was clear enough, so I'm glad to add details as needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the constraints on solving this problem? The obvious thing is to use a semaphore and just move code around so that either block of code acquires the semaphore before using the socket and releases afterwards. But I get the feeling you don't want to do that. So what can we change and what can we not change?

Comment: You got the right feeling. The thing is that I'm trying to patch up some badly written code, and I haven't had much time to fully fix the code, as a matter of a fact, I decided to fully rewrite it, but in the mean time some fixing needs to be done, so that's why I'm being overcautious with changing the "discipline" of the code. But I think the answer given by @AlexNetrebesky will work without being too drastic of a change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it suites for you. Please try to use additional AutoResetEvent. Like this:

```
var _additionalControl = new AutoResetEvent(false);

// code gap

var networkStream = _clientSocket.GetStream();
networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, Convert.ToInt32(_clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize));
_additionalControl.Set();
_mainthreadControl.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite);

// code gap

try
{
  //some code
  _mainthreadControl.Reset();
  _additionalControl.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite);
   //some code that uses the same socket as above

  _mainthreadControl.Set();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  //ignored
}
```

In turn I recommend to use `System.Threading.Monitor` class, cause it's more faster than ManualResetEvent(false), because it's restricted by the single process. If course if you don't need to use lock in another program.

Comment: `AutoResetEvent` has a slim version, which is nearly as fast as the `Monitor` usage.